# How to index a DataFrame based on the number of consecutive days

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, indexing, slice

I've a pandas dataframe with an irregular datetime index. Now I would like to index the dataframe based on continuous consecutive observations. In other words, I only want to keep the values were there are `x` or more consecutive observations.

Take the following example:

```
idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2003-04-11', '2003-04-12', '2003-04-13','2003-04-17','2003-05-02', '2003-05-03', '2003-05-04','2003-07-23', '2003-07-24'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((9,2)),index=idx)
df
              0        1
2003-04-11    0.954287 0.331016    
2003-04-12    0.553477 0.858590    
2003-04-13    0.179510 0.103970     
2003-04-17    0.608664 0.746860     
2003-05-02    0.691829 0.081192     
2003-05-03    0.790748 0.319989     
2003-05-04    0.955903 0.668918     
2003-07-23    0.630201 0.297902     
2003-07-24    0.692403 0.847222
```

There are 3 consecutive observations from `2003-04-11 ~ 13`, then a single observation on `2003-04-17`, than another 3 consecutive observations from `2003-05-02 ~ 04` and it ends with two consecutive observations from `2003-07-23 ~ 24`.

How can I index these observations that are consecutive for 3 days or more? In this example it should keep the following observations:

```
              0        1
2003-04-11    0.954287 0.331016    
2003-04-12    0.553477 0.858590    
2003-04-13    0.179510 0.103970   
2003-05-02    0.691829 0.081192     
2003-05-03    0.790748 0.319989     
2003-05-04    0.955903 0.668918
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although answer is accepted, you can try different approach:

```
df1 = df.loc[df.groupby((~(df.index.to_series().diff() ==  pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d'))).astype(int).cumsum() ).transform(len).iloc[:, 0] == 3]
print df1
                   0         1
2003-04-11  0.350339  0.904514
2003-04-12  0.903141  0.423335
2003-04-13  0.394534  0.803299
2003-05-02  0.158032  0.565684
2003-05-03  0.715311  0.772509
2003-05-04  0.136462  0.533705
```

Step by step:

```
print ~(df.index.to_series().diff() ==  pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d'))
#2003-04-11     True
#2003-04-12    False
#2003-04-13    False
#2003-04-17     True
#2003-05-02     True
#2003-05-03    False
#2003-05-04    False
#2003-07-23     True
#2003-07-24    False
#dtype: bool

print (~(df.index.to_series().diff() ==  pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d'))).astype(int)
#2003-04-11    1
#2003-04-12    0
#2003-04-13    0
#2003-04-17    1
#2003-05-02    1
#2003-05-03    0
#2003-05-04    0
#2003-07-23    1
#2003-07-24    0
#dtype: int32
print (~(df.index.to_series().diff() ==  pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d'))).astype(int).cumsum()
#2003-04-11    1
#2003-04-12    1
#2003-04-13    1
#2003-04-17    2
#2003-05-02    3
#2003-05-03    3
#2003-05-04    3
#2003-07-23    4
#2003-07-24    4
#dtype: int32
```

```
print df.groupby((~(df.index.to_series().diff() ==  pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d'))).astype(int).cumsum()).transform(len)
#            0  1
#2003-04-11  3  3
#2003-04-12  3  3
#2003-04-13  3  3
#2003-04-17  1  1
#2003-05-02  3  3
#2003-05-03  3  3
#2003-05-04  3  3
#2003-07-23  2  2
#2003-07-24  2  2
print df.groupby((~(df.index.to_series().diff() ==  pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d'))).astype(int).cumsum()).transform(len).iloc[:, 0]
#2003-04-11    3
#2003-04-12    3
#2003-04-13    3
#2003-04-17    1
#2003-05-02    3
#2003-05-03    3
#2003-05-04    3
#2003-07-23    2
#2003-07-24    2
#Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

```
print df.groupby((~(df.index.to_series().diff() ==  pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d'))).astype(int).cumsum()).transform(len).iloc[:, 0] == 3
#2003-04-11     True
#2003-04-12     True
#2003-04-13     True
#2003-04-17    False
#2003-05-02     True
#2003-05-03     True
#2003-05-04     True
#2003-07-23    False
#2003-07-24    False
#Name: 0, dtype: bool
print df.loc[df.groupby((~(df.index.to_series().diff() ==  pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d'))).astype(int).cumsum()).transform(len).iloc[:, 0] == 3]
#                   0         1
#2003-04-11  0.120301  0.635707
#2003-04-12  0.747283  0.681601
#2003-04-13  0.118192  0.777899
#2003-05-02  0.481396  0.294547
#2003-05-03  0.619790  0.058048
#2003-05-04  0.179386  0.348843
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it also works for my requirement that it detects if there are more than 3 consecutive observations (change to `>= 3`). It's also a bit quicker as there is no double for loop. All in all it's a better answer

Comment: Glad can help you! Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

This works on the assumption that the index is sorted and that all values are ascending, basically we identify the rows that differ by 2 days when subtracting the row label from 2 rows apart (using `shift`) I then perform a list comprehension to generate the ranges, sort them and use them to index using `loc`:

```
In [133]:
row_labels = df.index[(df.index.to_series() - df.index.to_series().shift(2)) == pd.Timedelta(2, unit='d')]
rows = [x - pd.Timedelta(n, unit='d') for n in range(0,3) for x in row_labels]
rows = sorted(rows)
df.loc[rows]

Out[133]:
                   0         1
2003-04-11  0.352054  0.228887
2003-04-12  0.776784  0.594784
2003-04-13  0.137554  0.852900
2003-05-02  0.589869  0.574012
2003-05-03  0.061270  0.590426
2003-05-04  0.245350  0.340445
```

You can see the result of the initial calculation:

```
In [134]:
df.index[(df.index.to_series() - df.index.to_series().shift(2)) == pd.Timedelta(2, unit='d')]

Out[134]:
DatetimeIndex(['2003-04-13', '2003-05-04'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```